# Collection of Collections - Refer to SubCollection Item with Variable for Primary Collection

Tags: vba, vba7

I’m using (as example) a UserForm with six TextBoxes on a 3x2 matrix: like this:

```
c1  c2  c3
c4  c5  c6
```

I’m trying to add both of these Rows of TextBoxes to a Collection (secondary) and then add this Collections to a Collection (primary) of Collection.
And then refer to an object in the nested Collection (secondary)  with a variable for the Collection in the primary Collection.
Like: The “Collection (primary).First Element. Collection (secondary).Third Element.name” is c3.

I’ve tried to read and implement [Referencing an object within a collection of collections by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498004/referencing-an-object-within-a-collection-of-collections-by-key) or [Collection of Collections - How to make sub-collections by value rather than reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40745720/collection-of-collections-how-to-make-sub-collections-by-value-rather-than-ref), and I also tried with a Dictionary like suggested [Dynamically Create collection of Collections VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998132/dynamically-create-collection-of-collections-vba), but I keep getting:

**Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method**

On this line( or in one of the line variations posted in the code below):

```
If rigavar.ItemCollection(q)(3).Name = "c3" Then
```

I’ve tried to understand and adapt those examples but I just can’t get it done and I don’t know if I’m missing something or I’m doing it completely wrong or if I just didn’t understand how things works or all of them.

I got a workaround by creating just a collection for each row and by creating a specific procedure for  each single collection.
When the Routine reach a certain Collection, it fires the Routine with the specific references for that Collection, something like this:

```
Private Sub workaround_Click() 
    Set rigaAA = New Collection
    rigaAA.Add c1
    rigaAA.Add c2
    rigaAA.Add c3
    
    Set rigaBB = New Collection
    rigaBB.Add c4
    rigaBB.Add c5
    rigaBB.Add c6
    
    If rigaAA.ItemCollection(3).Name = "c3" Then
    
    Call rigaAAspecificRoutine
        
        End if
    End sub

    Private Sub rigaAAspecificRoutine()
        MsgBox c1.value & c2.value  & c3.value
    End sub
```

But I was hoping to get it done by variables instead of specific, something like:

```
Private Sub test_Click()

Dim rigaAA As VBA.Collection
Dim rigaBB As VBA.Collection
Dim rigavar As VBA.Collection

Set rigaAA = New Collection
rigaAA.Add c1
rigaAA.Add c2
rigaAA.Add c3

Set rigaBB = New Collection
rigaBB.Add c4
rigaBB.Add c5
rigaBB.Add c6

Set rigavar = New Collection
rigavar.Add rigaAA
rigavar.Add rigaBB

'none of this works:

For q = 1 To 2
    If rigavar.ItemCollection(q)(3).Name = "c3" Then
        MsgBox c1.value & c2.value  & c3.value
    End If
Next

For q = 1 To 2
    If rigavar.ItemCollection(q)(3).Name = "c3" Then
        MsgBox c1.value & c2.value  &  c3.value
    End If
Next

For q = 1 To 2
    If rigavar.ItemCollection(q, 3).Name = "c3" Then
        MsgBox c1.value & c2.value  & c3.value
    End If
Next

For q = 1 To 2
    If rigavar.ItemCollection(q).ItemCollection(3).Value <> "" Then
        MsgBox c1.value & c2.value  & c3.value
    End If
Next
    
End Sub
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks a lot

Comment: To access the inner collection, the syntax would be `rigavar(q)(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Collection` has no property `ItemCollection`. To access element `q` of collection `rigavar`, you can use one of the following methods

```
rigavar(q)
rigavar.Item(q)
```

(Usually, the shorter form is used, this is basically an abbreviation to the longer form as the `Item` property is the so called *default property* of a collection).

As the element `rigavar(q)` is again a Collection, you can access the 3rd element with

```
rigavar(q)(3)
rigavar.Item(q)(3)
rigavar.Item(q).Item(3)
```

Easiest way to check the name of the control, use `rigavar(q)(3).Name`

What you can't do is to write `rigavar(q, 3)` because now VBA would take both parameters as parameters into rigavar.Item (as if it was a 2-dimensional array).

Comment: Thanks a lot. So it was just a silly mistake of syntax and lack of knowledge of the properties of Collections. I'm going to implement and try this in minutes. Thanks again for your time and the explanation.